# Product of two path-connected spaces, is path-connected.

Tags: general-topology

> If $(X, \mathcal T)$ and $(Y, \mathcal T_1)$ are path-connected spaces, prove that $(X, \mathcal T)\times(Y,\mathcal T_1)$ is path-connected.

Let $x_1, x_2 \in X$ and $y_1, y_2 \in Y$.

Since $X$ and $Y$ are path-connected, there exists continuous functions $f:[0,1]\to X$ and $g:[0,1]\to Y$ such that $f(0)=x_1, f(1)=x_2, g(0)=y_1, g(1)=y_2$.

Now define $h:[0,1] \to X\times Y$ by $$h(x)=(f(x),g(x)).$$
Then clearly $h(0)=(x_1,y_1)$ and $h(1)=(x_2,y_2).$

I need now only show that $h$ is, in fact continuous. However, I am not sure how to go about showing it. Can anyone please guide me in the right direction?

Comment: Use the universal property for the product topology https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_topology#Properties.

Comment: Note that $\pi_X \circ h = f$ and $\pi_Y \circ h = g$ by construction, and these are continuous by assumption. NOw apply @LeeMosher's idea.